# Фактический размер изображения

Tags: javascript

Функция получает элемент, берет из него свойство `src` и вот у нас есть обычная ссылка на изображение. Как узнать его оригинальный размер?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

С просторов интернета

```
function getImgSize(imgSrc) {
    var newImg = new Image();

    newImg.onload = function() {
        var height = newImg.height;
        var width = newImg.width;
        console.log('The image size is '+width+'*'+height);
    }

    newImg.src = imgSrc; // this must be done AFTER setting onload
}
```

Использование getImgSize($('img').attr('src'))

Comment: спасибо, а то сам не нашёл:(